# Solve PDE involving implicit function of independent variables

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I have a differential equation given by

```
-4*D[S[u,v],u,v]==V[u,v]*S[u,v]
```

with boundary conditions

```
S[0,v]==Exp[-(v-vc)^2/(2*sigma^2)]
S[u,0]==Exp[-(-vc)^2/(2*sigma^2)]

V[u,v]=(1-a/r-b*r^2)*((l*(1+l))/r^2+(a/r^2-2*b*r)/r)
```

where `r` should be determined from

```
v-u=2*Integrate[1/(1-a/r-b*r^2),r]
```

(NOTE: `l` is a nonzero positive integer, and `a` and `b` are two nonzero positive numbers. "It is possible to use numbers instead of `a`, `b`, and `l` through calculations")  Indeed, I know that I should use discretization to solve this equation because I solved a simpler case with `b=0`. As a point, I used

```
First[NDSolve[
    {-4*D[S[u, v], u, v] == V[u, v]* S[u, v],S[u,0]==Exp[-(-vc)^2/2*sigma^2)],
     S[0,v]==Exp[-(v-vc)^2/(2*sigma^2)]},S, {u, 0, 400}, {v, 0, 400},
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> 
     {"TensorProductGrid","MaxStepSize" -> 0.1}}, AccuracyGoal -> 10]]
```

to solve the simpler case. But there is a problem here. `r` cannot be calculated straightforwardly from `v-u=2*Integrate[1/(1-a/r-b*r^2),r]`.

One can use `a=1`, `l=1`, `b=1/16`, `vc=10`, and `sigma=3` for numerical analysis.

As the final remark, maybe it is possible to use Runge-Kutta method for the integration, interpolates the function at each step and finally finds `r` as
a function of `u` and `v`. But I do not know how I can do it :(

I will be really thankful if someone help.

Comment: If this equation is to be solved numerically, please provide values for all constants.

Comment: @bbgodfrey `a=1`, `l=1`, `b=1/16`, `vc=10`, and `sigma=3`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I checked that answer and found out it is wrong (see comment below it). If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: `v - u = 2*Integrate[1/(1-a/r-b*r^2), r]` yields `v - u = 2/(b r) `for small `v - u`, which does not seem credible to me. Perhaps, you mean `v - u = c + 2*Integrate[1/(1-a/r-b*r^2), r]`. If so, what is `c`? Once this is resolved, solving the problem should be straightforward.

Comment: @bbgodfrey No, there is no `c` beside the integral. I am sure about this. I know the method that should be used to solve the problem, but I do not know how I can apply it. The answer is given below is good but it has a problem. `r=NDSolveValue[{D[r0[x], x] == (1 - a/r0[x] - b*r0[x]^2)/2, 
   r0[-x0] == 1}, r0, {x, -x0, x0}]` gives an unique value for `r[x]` for all `x` because `NDSolveValue` cannot solve this equation. This is the solution: we should write a code to solve this equation with small steps from `-x0` to `x0`, not this big interval `{x, -x0, x0}`. Did you get it?

Comment: Indefinite integrals are arbitrary up to a constant.  So, for `u - v == 0`, what value should `r` have?  Note also that `r=NDSolveValue[{D[r0[x], x] == (1 - a/r0[x] - b*r0[x]^2)/2, r0[-x0] == 1}, r0, {x, -x0, x0}]` is not constant, and also that that it involves an arbitrary constant, `x0`, which happens to be set to `800` here.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Dear friend, I really tried to explain and open this problem and tell it in an easy way. But obviously I could not, and I know that it was my weakness that could not explain the problem well. I am really thankful for the generous help and spending time. As the final point, I want you to have a look at pages 3 and 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9902010v2.pdf. Maybe it explains this problem easier. Best wishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    a = 1; b = 1/16; x0 = 800; r = 
 NDSolveValue[{D[r0[x], x] == (1 - a/r0[x] - b*r0[x]^2)/2, 
   r0[-x0] == 1 + I*10^-10}, r0, {x, -x0, x0}]
vc = 10; sigma = 3; l = 1;
S0[u_, v_] := Exp[-(v - vc)^2/(2*sigma^2)]
eq = {-4*D[S[u, v], u, v] == V[Re[r[v - u]]]*S[u, v]};
bc = {S[0, v] == S0[0, v], S[u, 0] == S0[u, 0]};
V[x_] := (1 - a/x - b*x^2)*((l*(1 + l))/x^2 + (a/x^2 - 2*b*x)/x)
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, S, {u, 0, x0}, {v, 0, x0}]
{Plot3D[Re[sol[u, v]], {u, 0, x0}, {v, 0, x0}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"u", "v"}], 
 Plot[Re[r[x]], {x, -x0, -x0 + 10}, AxesLabel -> {"v-u", "r"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Orange, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Re[r[x]], {x, -x0, x0}, AxesLabel -> {"v-u", "r"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Orange, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig2]

After numerous discussions with the author of the topic, I decided to add a solution to the problem on the basis of my numerical model, but with the data that Godfrey used. As can be seen from the data given, there is a coincidence and a difference. At first, the maximum of the function $V(x)$ is shifted to the left with respect to 0, and in the Godfrey solution the maximum is shifted to the right. The author of the theme asserts that the maximum should be shifted to the left. And he sent me the appropriate decision, with which I agree. Secondly, there are differences in solution, which is due to the first difference.

```
a = 1; b = 1/16; x0 = 100;
R1 = -4.42863948675507037483099540169716097781583927443899886866276463\
30182560928665325495919425006839287038680064401788392`100.;
R2 = 1.078377745621778233051751805397040016199774219084253403438456893\
3353720068855339101075303006206231499526837887379443`100.;
R3 = 3.350261741133292141779243596300120961616065055354745465224307739\
6828840859809986394844122000633055539153226514408949`100.;
ndvar = -16`100 ((Log[r - R1] R1)/(-16 + 3 R1^2) + (
     Log[r - R2] R2)/(-16 + 3 R2^2) + (Log[R3 - r] R3)/(-16 + 3 R3^2));
r00 = r /. 
    FindRoot[ndvar == 0, {r, 11/10`100}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, 
     MaxIterations -> 10000, PrecisionGoal -> 100, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 100]; // Quiet
r = NDSolveValue[{D[r0[x], x] == (1 - a/r0[x] - b*r0[x]^2)/2, 
   r0[0] == r00}, r0, {x, -x0, x0}]
vc = 10; sigma = 3; l = 1;
S0[u_, v_] := Exp[-(v - vc)^2/(2*sigma^2)]
eq = {-4*D[S[u, v], u, v] == V[Re[r[v - u]]]*S[u, v]};
bc = {S[0, v] == S0[0, v], S[u, 0] == S0[u, 0]};
V[x_] := (1 - a/x - b*x^2)*((l*(1 + l))/x^2 + (a/x^2 - 2*b*x)/x)
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, S, {u, 0, x0}, {v, 0, x0}]
{Plot3D[Re[sol[u, v]], {u, 0, x0}, {v, 0, x0}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"u", "v"}], 
 Plot[V[Re[r[x]]], {x, -50, 50}, AxesLabel -> {"v-u", "V"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Orange, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Re[r[x]], {x, -20, 60}, AxesLabel -> {"v-u", "r"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Orange, PlotRange -> All], 
 LogLogPlot[Abs[sol[50, v]], {v, 5, x0}]}
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: Good work. But did you check the values of `r[x]` for different `x`'s? They are the same! Also, you have applied the wrong boundary conditions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This answer has a problem. `r=NDSolveValue[{D[r0[x], x] == (1 - a/r0[x] - b*r0[x]^2)/2, r0[-x0] == 1}, r0, {x, -x0, x0}]` gives an unique value for `r[x]` for all `x` because `NDSolveValue` cannot solve this equation. This is the solution: we should write a code to solve this equation with small steps from `-x0` to `x0`, not this big interval `{x, -x0, x0}`. But I do not know how I can do this.

Comment: I showed the working code, and you can play with the parameters, substitute any initial values and look for solutions. Good luck!

Comment: Mehrab, I did not see your answer with the data for the parameters when I was preparing my code. I made some improvement to cover this case and published a new code and picture..

Comment: Dear friend, I really tried to explain and open this problem and tell it in an easy way. But obviously I could not, and I know that it was my weakness that could not explain the problem well. I am really thankful for the generous help and spending time. As the final point, I want you to have a look at pages 3 and 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9902010v2.pdf. Maybe it explains this problem easier. Best wishes.

Comment: Mecrab, thank you for the link to the article. Do you think we should reproduce their calculations?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  How did you decide that `r0[-x0] == 1 + I*10^-10`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Dear Alex, not at all. I do not expect someone to read this paper and reproduce it. It can be hard and take a lot of time, and indeed, it is a great request. As I said in my last comment, I tried to explain and open this problem, but I could not. However, I shared the link of the original problem to show you that this problem cannot be obtained in the way that you mentioned as the answer to this question. Also, your code produces some results, but it is not the correct answer. It is more complicated...NEXT COMMENT...

Comment: ... I think the only problem of your revised code that is required to solve the integral with small steps from `-x0` to `x0`, not this big interval `{x, -x0, x0}`.Thanks for spending time.

Comment: bbgodfrey, there are three branches of the solution - one real and two complex. For the parameters indicated by the author, there are only complex solutions, so I took the initial data in the form of a complex number.

Comment: Mehrab, although I'm very busy, but I'll try to reproduce FIG. 1 from this article.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Dear Alex, If you do this, I will be thankful forever.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  If you post your email, I will send you two Mathematical files in this context that can be very useful and help to figure out the problem. I bet when you see them, you will solve my problem very fast.

Comment: Dear Mehrab, send letters to admin@likalo.com

Comment: In this article there is a simple error that Mathematics diagnoses as `NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.` If you take it without paying attention to this error, then you can get similar to Fig. 1 results, using my code.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Dear Alex, I sent you an email. Could you please send me your code via email?

Answer (score 5):

Before beginning, it is important to observe that Eq. (2.10) in the [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9902010v2.pdf) cited by the OP is incorrect.  Because `r0 < 0`, as stated earlier in the article, the argument of `Log[r/r0 - 1]` is strictly negative, which is nonphysical.  In fact, the term should be `Log[1 - r/r0]`.  This observation is important, because one of the stated goals of the question is to determine an analogous result for the parameters in the question.

Begin by performing the integration in the question relating `v - u` to `r`.

```
int = 2 Integrate[1/(1 - a/r - b*r^2) /. {a -> 1, b -> 1/16}, r] // Normal
(* -32 ((Log[r - Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 1]] Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 1])
            /(-16 + 3 Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 1]^2) 
      + (Log[r - Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 2]] Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 2])
            /(-16 + 3 Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 2]^2) 
      + (Log[r - Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 3]] Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 3])
            /(-16 + 3 Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 3]^2)) *)
```

plus a constant of integration to be determined.  Singularities occur at

```
Cases[int, _Root, 3];
%//N
(* {-4.42864, 1.07838, 3.35026} *)
```

which readily are identified as the quantities `{r0, re, rc}` appearing in the article.  According to the article, `r0 == -(re + rc)`, which also is true here.

```
FullSimplify[Total@Rest@%% == -First@%%]
(* True *)
```

Next, transform `int` to the form of the corrected Eq. (2.10).

```
dvar = int /. {Log[r - z_] /; z > 0 -> Log[r/z - 1], 
               Log[r - z_] /; z < 0 -> Log[-r/z + 1]} /.
     Log[-1 + r/Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 3]] -> Log[1 - r/Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 3]]
(* -32 ((Log[1 - r/Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 1]] Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 1])
       /(-16 + 3 Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 1]^2) 
   + (Log[-1 + r/Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 2]] Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 2])
       /(-16 + 3 Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 2]^2) 
   + (Log[1 - r/Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 3]] Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 3])
       /(-16 + 3 Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, 3]^2)) *)
```

plus constants terms proportional to `Root[16 - 16 #1 + #1^3 &, -]` and to `I Pi` that can be absorbed into the constant of integration, which we now set equal to zero to obtain the expression matching the right side of the corrected Eq. (2.10).  A plot of `dvar` follows.

```
ParametricPlot[{dvar, r}, {r, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
    AxesLabel -> {"u - v", r}, ImageSize -> Large,
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Next, compute the potential as a function of `v - u`.

```
V = Simplify[(1 - a/r - b*r^2)*((l*(1 + l))/r^2 + (a/r^2 - 2*b*r)/r) 
    /. {a -> 1, b -> 1/16} /. l -> 1];
ndvar = N@dvar;
fV[z_?NumericQ] := If[Abs[z] < 50, Re[V /. FindRoot[ndvar == z, {r, 11/10}]], 0];
Plot[fV[x], {x, -50, 50}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"v - u", "V"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

The exponential decrease in  `V` for large `Abs[v - u]` justifies setting it to zero for `Abs[v - u] > 50`.  Doing so save much computing time.  Finally, compute and plot the solution of the PDE.

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{-4*D[S[u, v], u, v] == fV[v - u]*S[u, v], 
   S[u, 0] == Exp[-(-vc)^2/(2*sigma^2)], 
   S[0, v] == Exp[-(v - vc)^2/(2*sigma^2)]} /. {vc -> 10, sigma -> 3}, 
   S, {u, 0, 100}, {v, 0, 100}, MaxStepSize -> .1];
Plot3D[sol[u, v], {u, 0, 100}, {v, 0, 100}, AxesLabel -> {u, v, S}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}, PlotRange -> All,
    PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

A slice through `v - u` space at constant `u`, plotted logarithmically shows oscillations that otherwise are hard to see.

```
LogLogPlot[Abs[sol[50, v]], {v, 5, 100}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

Comment: bbgodfrey,  thank you for the solution of the problem. But how to get the data in Fig. 1 of this article using this solution?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  Thank you for suggesting that I add the third plot to my answer.  Note that the parameters used to obtain Figure 1 do not appear to match those contained in the question.

Comment: Thank you, your solution of the problem is very close to what we are discussing referring to the article. But there are a couple of mistakes in the article, one of which you pointed out, and I pointed to the other. The question arises, should we continue to refer to the article or stop at your solution?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  I believe that we have answered the question but look forward to hearing from Mehrab.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Dear Godfrey, it seems to me that your answer to this question is correct mathematically. Thank you very much for spending time and solving mine problem. But let me help if you want to reproduce Fig. 1 of the paper. I was working on your code to reproduce it but I couldn't yet. However, I know how to reproduce it. The potential barrier must be real and positive in the tortoise coordinate between `re` and `rc`. Indeed, this problem should be solved for this range `[re,rc]`, because it is our real accessible spacetime... Please see next comment...

Comment: ...Maybe you should use something like `Log[r - z_] /; z < 0 -> Log[-r/z + 1], Log[r - z_] /; 0 < z < 2 -> Log[r/z - 1], Log[r - z_] /; z > 2 -> Log[1 - r/z]` in `dvar`. Therefore, `dvar` will change into `-16 ((Log[r - R1] R1)/(-16 + 3 R1^2) + (
   Log[r - R2] R2)/(-16 + 3 R2^2) + (Log[R3 - r] R3)/(-16 + 3 R3^2))` with `R1 = -4.4286`, `R2 = 1.0783`, and `R3 = 3.3502`. And this leades in a real positve potential form `-infinity` to `infinity` in the tortoise coordinate `r*` or equivalently in the range `[re,rc]` in common coordinate `r`. Also, its Max is located before `v-u=0` not after it...

Comment: ...After doing this and solving the differential equation, you can use a table with `Table[{t, sol[t - 10, t + 10] }, {t, 10, ????, 1/50}]` form and plot it in LogLog case. Therefore, the Fig. 1 will reproduce. If you need more information or explanations, please let me know. 
@AlexTrounev

Comment: I cannot look at this until tomorrow.  Thanks,

Comment: @bbgodfrey Dear Godfrey, please note that your answer to my question asked here is correct. If you are not interested in reproducing that figure, it does not matter. I am very close to reproducing it. Anyway, if you are interested to see the final result, you can post your email and I will send you the final result. I really thank you very much for your nice answer and spending time. Best wishes.